# Querying models not working correctly - Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently learning Django and as an exercise I have written a simple model, a view and couple of templates. The purpose of my app is to query the books in my database that contain a specific term in their 'title' field. I have written a 'Book' model for the same, a view function to query the books using the 'Book' model and return the results to a template 'search-results.html'. The query term is passed from an HTML form. I am able to receive the query string from the 'request' object, but when I query the 'Book' model for results, I get an empty list. I tried querying the 'Book' model from the python shell and it works perfectly fine. Why am I not getting any result from my view function? The following is the code in my view function:

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
        return render(request,'search-results.html',{'results':books,'query':q})
    else:
        message = 'You submitted an empty form'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

The following is the code for my search form:

```
<form action='/search/' method='get'>
        <input type='text' name='q'>
        <input type='submit' value='Search'>
</form>
```

The query term I used is 'Django'. The following is the table data:

```
mysql> select * from books_book;
+----+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+
| id | title           | publisher_id | publicationDate |
+----+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+
|  1 | Learning Python |            1 | 2014-09-02      |
|  2 | Learning Django |            2 | 2014-09-28      |
+----+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following is the results template:

```
<body>
        <p>
            The following are the {{books|length}} results for the search term {{query}}:
            {% for book in books %}
                <li>{{book.title}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
    </body>
```

I am using Django 1.6 and Python 2.7.8, MySQL 5.6

Thank you,
Rakesh.

Comment: And what does the results template look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying over `books` in your templates, whereas you name the variable `results` when you *pass* it to your template in the view.

In your template try iterating over `results` instead of `books`:

```
{% for book in results %}
    <li>{{book.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

which would result in:

```
<body>
    <p>
        The following are the {{results|length}} results for the search term {{query}}:
        {% for book in results %}
            <li>{{book.title}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you guys, a rookie mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You called your context variable containing the books "results", but in the template you are iterating through "books". Pick one and be consistent.